# Não consigo adicionar itens no scroolview

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou usando esse scroolview porém preciso colocar novos itens embaixo , e quando eu rolo para baixo não desce , poderiam me ajudar?
segue codigo xml : https://pastebin.com/x6aVUUjr

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sem ver o código XML não tem como ajudar.

Comment: editei marcio ..

Answer (score 2):

No trecho de código abaixo, troque o `RelativeLayout` por `LinearLayout`, troque o`1000sp` por `wrap_content` e adicione um `android:orientation="vertical"`:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="1000sp">
```

Nos CardViews, pode remover esses atributos:

- android:layout_alignParentTop
- android:layout_below

Comment: Fiz isso mas nao deu certo não

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar mais itens simplesmente redimensione a janela de pré-visualização carregando no canto inferior direito e arrastando até ficar com espaço para mais itens.

Comment: dessa forma até que deu certo , mas tem a outra forma que voce rola o mouse pra baixo e vai descendo e voce adicionando itens